# PySpark filtering on multiple criteria

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, filtering

My example (dataframe) is like this:

```
Name    ID     ContractDate LoanSum ClosingDate
A       ID1    2022-10-10   10      2022-10-16 
A       ID1    2022-10-10   15      2022-10-18
A       ID1    2022-10-20   20      2022-10-31
A       ID1    2022-10-20   20      2022-10-30
A       ID1    2022-11-10   14      2022-11-22
A       ID1    2022-11-10   15      2022-11-22

B       ID2    2022-11-11   15      2022-11-15
B       ID2    2022-11-11   30      2022-11-18
B       ID2    2022-11-17   35      2022-11-22
B       ID2    2022-11-17   35      2022-11-24

C       ID3    2022-12-19   19      2022-11-10
```

My goal is to create a new dataframe that contains all loans issued to specific borrowers (group by unique ID) given the following conditions:

- two loans should be granted at the same day;
- next two loans should be also granted at the same day but the time difference between ClosingDate of any of the previously issued loans should not exceed 5 days from the newly issued two loans.

In other words my desirable outcome is like this:

```
Name    ID     ContractDate LoanSum ClosingDate
A       ID1    2022-10-10   10      2022-10-16 
A       ID1    2022-10-10   15      2022-10-18
A       ID1    2022-10-20   20      2022-10-31
A       ID1    2022-10-20   20      2022-10-30
```

(the difference between first ClosingDate and next ContractDate in this example is 4 (2020-10-20 minus 2022-10-16))

I've performed the following code that gives me an opportunity to get two or more loans issued to a specific borrower at the same date (grouped by ID):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF('Name','ID','ContractDate','LoanSum','ClosingDate')
df.show()

cols = df.columns
w = Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('ContractDate')

df.withColumn('PreviousContractDate', f.lag('ContractDate').over(w)) \
  .withColumn('Target', f.expr('datediff(ContractDate, PreviousContractDate) == 0')) \
  .withColumn('Target', f.col('Target') | f.lead('Target').over(w)) \
  .filter('Target == True')
```

But I am stuck to filter.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupBy` to get the loans info for a day and apply the conditions by using the `Window`.

```
w = Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('MaxClosingDate')

df.groupBy('Name', 'ID', 'ContractDate') \
  .agg(
      f.collect_list(f.struct('LoanSum', 'ClosingDate')).alias('LoanInfo'),
      f.max('ClosingDate').alias('MaxClosingDate')
  ) \
  .withColumn('is2LoanTarget', f.size('LoanInfo') == 2) \
  .withColumn('is5DaysTarget', f.datediff(f.col('ContractDate'), f.lag('MaxClosingDate').over(w)).between(0, 5)) \
  .withColumn('is5DaysTarget', f.col('is5DaysTarget') | f.lead('is5DaysTarget').over(w)) \
  .filter('is2LoanTarget and is5DaysTarget') \
  .withColumn('LoanInfo', f.explode('LoanInfo')) \
  .select('Name', 'ID', 'ContractDate', 'LoanInfo.*') \
  .show()

+----+---+------------+-------+-----------+
|Name| ID|ContractDate|LoanSum|ClosingDate|
+----+---+------------+-------+-----------+
|   A|ID1|  2022-10-10|     10| 2022-10-16|
|   A|ID1|  2022-10-10|     15| 2022-10-18|
|   A|ID1|  2022-10-20|     20| 2022-10-31|
|   A|ID1|  2022-10-20|     20| 2022-10-30|
+----+---+------------+-------+-----------+
```